# Why is the click function unable to apply more than one random index to my arrays

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'm stuck on the random quote machine project on Free Code Camp. I can generate random quotes and colors but they are only generated once using the click event. Subsequent clicks of the "New quote" button generate new random indexing for my colors and quotes array.

```js
var quote = ["It is not the size of the dog in the fight, but the size of the fight in the dog.-Archie Griffen", "Nothing lasts forever. Not even your troubles.-Arnold H Glasgow", "There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle-Albert Einstein"];

// problem area
var col = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "brown"];
var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * col.length);
var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.length);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(".quote-window").html(quote[j]);
    $("body").css("background-color", col[i]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Firstly, please take care to format your question properly. Code goes in to code blocks, not quote blocks. Secondly, if someone takes the time to format your question for you, don't just overwrite it and screw it all up again. I'll let you fix it this time

Comment: Please format your question properly with at least four spaces before every line. At the moment it's unreadable, and so is unanswerable. Thanks! :)

Comment: i am using a phone so I can't use the ctrl+k to indent the code.

Comment: Then use four spaces. Also myself and @Satpal edited the formatting for you, and you still managed to screw it over again. Twice.

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't know. I won't touch it again. Pls help me adjust it if you have a PC there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate variable `i` and `j` in the `<button>` click handler.

```js
var quote = ["It is not the size of the dog in the fight, but the size of the fight in the dog.-Archie Griffen",
  "Nothing lasts forever. Not even your troubles.-Arnold H Glasgow",
  "There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle-Albert Einstein"
];
var col = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "brown"];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * col.length);
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.length);
    $(".quote-window").html(quote[j]);
    $("body").css("background-color", col[i]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click Me</button>
<div class='quote-window'></div>
```

Comment: Wow!!. Now I get it. Thanks. You've made my day

Comment: Pls I can no longer ask questions again on this site. I've been banned for 6months. I've edited my question. So I need upvotes  on this question in order to lift the ban.

Answer (score 1):

You get the `i` and `j` variables outside the click function and never change them. That's why when you click on the button, `j` and `i` already have values and they won't change.

Add those variable declarations inside the click function. See below

There is a possibility that the random generated numbers are the same with the previous generated number, to make sure that doesn't happen there's a little more work to be done. But you have a very good starting point with the below code.

```js
var quote = ["It is not the size of the dog in the fight, but the size of the fight in the dog.-Archie Griffen", "Nothing lasts forever. Not even your troubles.-Arnold H Glasgow", "There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle-Albert Einstein"];

// problem area
var col = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "brown"];



$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * col.length);
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.length);
    $(".quote-window").html(quote[j]);
    $("body").css("background-color", col[i]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  Click
</button>
<div class="quote-window">

</div>
```

Comment: What is the difference with the first answer?

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst you think it took <30 seconds to write this answer?

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst i was writing this answer while the first was posted, as you can see ( at this time ) for the both answers the time is `answered 2 mins ago`

Comment: I'm trying to ask a new question but I keep getting the "we are no longer receiving questions from this account". Why

Comment: I need upvotes on this question in order to lift my current ban on asking further questions.